# Issue encrypting string in C++ and decrypting in PHP

Tags: php, c++, mcrypt

I'm having an issue encrypting my string in C++ and then decrypting in PHP. On the C++ side, I think everything is going fine. Below is my code for the C++ side.

```
unsigned char inbuffer[1024];

unsigned char outbuffer[1024];

unsigned char oneKey[] = "abc";
AES_KEY key;

AES_set_encrypt_key(oneKey, 128, &key);

string straa("hello world\n");
memcpy((char*)inbuffer, straa.c_str(), 13);

AES_encrypt(inbuffer, encryptedbuffer, &key);

LPCSTR pszSource = (LPCSTR)encryptedbuffer;
DWORD nDestinationSize;
if (CryptBinaryToString(reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*> (pszSource), strlen(pszSource), CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, nullptr, &nDestinationSize))
{
    LPTSTR pszDestination = static_cast<LPTSTR> (HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE, nDestinationSize * sizeof(TCHAR)));
    if (pszDestination)
    {
        if (CryptBinaryToString(reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*> (pszSource), strlen(pszSource), CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, pszDestination, &nDestinationSize))
        {

            printf("OUT: %s", pszDestination); // Base64 encoded output of encrypted string


        }

    }
}
```

This is my PHP code:

```
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('AES-256-CBC'));
$out = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode("G6g0f/K7EzAw8fxn9BTFzw=="), 'AES-256-CBC', "abc", OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);

echo $out;
```

There is no output from the PHP code.

The C++ code would output the following:

```
OUT: G6g0f/K7EzAw8fxn9BTFzw==
```

Comment: I can't help here because I have no C++ experience but im intrigued (if you have the time to explain) what are you using a combination of C++ and PHP for?

Comment: Of course I have time. I am creating a login client which would transfer client to server data in AES to prevent people from viewing the network traffic.

Comment: Use HTTPS for securing the client to server communications.

Comment: 1. If a client is running my login client it is possible for him/her to decrypt HTTPS communications.
2. I supplied the IV in the first line of PHP code.

Comment: If you pin the certificate: no. Even the quarry string is encrypted, only the server address is not encrypted. If you do not pin the certificate a sophisticated user could use a proxy such as Charles Proxy.

Comment: No offense, but my question wasn't how to secure HTTPS. I really need the above fixed for absolute security.

Comment: In the C++ code the aes encrypt function doesn't ask/need one as a parameter. This is the declaration of the AES_Encrypt function. void AES_encrypt(const unsigned char *in, unsigned char *out,
                 const AES_KEY *key);

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, but I am not interested in using just HTTPS. Maybe someone experienced in both C++ & PHP can tell me what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CBC mode, the mode used in the PHP code, does require an iv and it must be the same as the one used for encryption, also the modes must be the same for both encryption and decryption. For CBC mode you need to supply a block sized iv (16-bytes for AES). The encryption key also should to be the correct size.

The iv is not explicitly set in the C++ code and the mode and padding use the default, it is always better to expel;icitly specify all parameters. The iv should be random for each encryption.

You might consider [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), it is multi language and platform and handles all the details.